# April Fool isn't for me? My Avatar does not change at all

Tags: support, gravatar, unicorns

I have set my gravatar to unicorn for a while already.

BUT I have expected to be changed too for today.

Why wouldn't you pass reversed hash to unicornify.appspot.com for example?

Then I could get something different like this.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The executive decision came out in favor of not retroactively applying the change to those who already voluntarily joined the Cornu Equus Rebellion.

Comment: not retroactively? but I'm seeing my avatar image links to unicornify.appspot.com, not gravatar.com

Answer (score 1):

Or you could get something like

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe that means that every day is April Fool's Day for you.  Is that a good thing?